# Conditional Regular Expressions [racket]

Tags: regex, racket

I see in the manual of Racket ([here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html)) the following structure:

```
(?‹tst›‹pces›|‹pces›) = Match 1st ‹pces› if ‹tst›, else 2nd ‹pces›
```

and the following example:

```
(regexp-match #rx"(?(?<=c)a|b)+" "cabal")
```

I do not understand it. In which situation/s this kind of regular expression may be useful ?

Comment: You don't understand the meaning of the regexp or you want a better use case?

Comment: I cannot imagine at all how this construction could be useful.

Comment: I think the meaning is: <<if the expression TST matches, then try to match next p1. else p2. >> . Right ? The problem is in which situations this is helpful. Never thought that such a construction could exist.

Comment: Yes, it means that. Exactly speaking, in `(?(condition)yes-pattern | no-pattern)`if condition is true, then only yes-pattern is considered, otherwise only no-pattern is considered. I haven't figured out a good use case at present.

Comment: Thanks . I am so eager to understand how this construction may be useful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called `conditional expression` in perl. And it is more clear to write as

```
(?(condition)yes-pattern|no-pattern)
```

It matches `yes-pattern` if `condition` yields a true value, matches `no-pattern` otherwise. A missing pattern always matches. Check perl doc for more info [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).(search "condition" in this page) This page gives almost all useful predicates, though not including examples.

Another example can be found [here](http://www.silverstones.com/thebat/RegexPt4.html#cond). There are two examples, English/European date format and one about mail titles.

And this one from [gnome developer doc](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-regex-syntax.html).(search for "conditional subpatterns" in this page) Several examples here. The parenthesis example is a classic one that can be also found in [perl regexp detailed manual](http://www.wellho.net/regex/perlre.html).